# Select2: search based on tags

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to have search box like below image.

https://plus.google.com/u/0/photos/114872147731683389826/albums/5843935056831072545?authkey=CKai5M3A-ePvogE

Can I have it with select2 plugin? If yes tell me the way how to do that? Or else point me any other way to do that

Comment: your link is not working..

Answer (score 1):

use jquery+msdropdown...have a [look here](http://www.marghoobsuleman.com/jquery-image-dropdown)...[demo](http://www.marghoobsuleman.com/mywork/jcomponents/image-dropdown/samples/index.html) here

built in jquery, easily customizable and fully skinable

Comment: That is only a combobox. See my link, first I have to select the search tag, and then I have to type the search text. Search result filtered based on the search text and selected tag.